# In Data Warehouse Foreign Key on Fact tables Necessary?

Tags: foreign-key

In DW, does ForeignKey have advantages other than data integrity?

For ongoing updates to DW, we have to enable and disable FKs and that causes locks and sometimes ends up causing deadlocks against select queries as victim.

Can someone please give some good scenarios of fks usage and how to handle the updates/insert against Datawarehouse ?

Comment: you shouldn't be having to enable and disable your foreign keys.  what is causing that?

Comment: @indiri this (along with disabling nonclustered indexes) is somewhat common in data warehouses to improve large data load speeds. Not saying it's always great, because there's a penalty to re-enable, but it's not unheard of.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I agree, but in those cases (large loads) that would generally happen in the "off hours" and not conflict with selects.  Incremental loads throughout the day are usually a lot smaller and probably less expensive to leave the keys in place then try pay the penalty for disable/reenable.

Comment: @indiri for incremental loads, the problem is likely cascading actions of foreign keys. They take out [serializable locks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2009/03/13/conor-vs-isolation-level-upgrade-on-updatedelete-cascading-ri/) while they perform each action, which can cause pretty bad locking problems under a lot of circumstances -- think really poor index choices, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you updating keys?  The proper fix isn't to disable/enable referential integrity, but instead use surrogate keys in your data warehouse.  That way if a user ID or some other "key" that has meaning is adjusted, you're not breaking RI to do so.

A summary from the master, [Ralph Kimball](http://www.kimballgroup.com/1998/05/surrogate-keys/), himself:

> In a data warehouse, a surrogate key is a necessary generalization of the natural production key and is one of the basic elements of data warehouse design. Let’s be very clear: Every join between dimension tables and fact tables in a data warehouse environment should be based on surrogate keys, not natural keys. It is up to the data extract logic to systematically look up and replace every incoming natural key with a data warehouse surrogate key each time either a dimension record or a fact record is brought into the data warehouse environment.

Check out the linked article as Kimball goes into more detail on why this approach is necessary for data warehousing.